# How to create a file if a condition holds and use it later in the program (under the same condition), in Java?

Tags: java, file

I want to create a file only if condition `c` is true, and update this file later in a loop (if the same condition is true). But if I create a file inside an if-statement it will not be accessible outside the if. For instance, if I create a file:

```
if(c){ 
   Writer outputFile = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
          new FileOutputStream("path_2_output_file"), "UTF-8"));
}
//...
```

And try to write into this file later in the program:

```
String l = "";
while ((l = someInputBuffer.readLine()) != null) {
   if(c){
      outputFile.write("new-"+l+"\n);
    }
}
```

But `outputFile` is not accessible/available because it was declared in the if-statement. How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is keep your Writer pointer outside the loop as such:

```
Writer w = null;
if(c) w= new Writer...;
loop{
    //Do Stuff
    if(w!=null)w.append("info");
}
```